# How can I restore ldap database with a ldif file?

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

I have an ldif file. I created it with this command:

```
kill -INT `cat /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid`
slapcat -v -f /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf -l /usr/local/etc/openldap_backup/backup.`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.ldif
```

And, I try to restore ldap database with:

```
slapadd -v -c -l backup.11-24-2017.ldif  -f /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf
```

But I have an error:

> could not add entry .... (line=777): txn_aborted! DB_KEYEXIST:
>   Key/data pair already exists (-30995)

How can I fix it?

Comment: The entry is already there. So it doesn't need restoring. You aren't starting with an empty database.

Comment: I have the similar issue; those entries are automatically created when it is installed... but prevent importing others

Answer (score 0):

to save 2h for someone else I'll post it in here...
you cannot use slapadd because not all entries are new.
In this case use ldapmodify

more info in here [How do I clone an OpenLDAP database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792563/how-do-i-clone-an-openldap-database)